# How can I send the rows of a matrix to another process with mpi?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I have a matrix A[10][10]. I want to send first row of this matrix to another process.
How can I do it?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Couldn't you at least pretend to have tried to program this yourself ?  This is just about the first thing that you learn from any MPI tutorial.  What have you tried ?

Answer (score 2):

```
Look at these pages:
```

http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Recv.html
http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Send.html

....A sample code:

```
if(rank==0){
MPI_Send(&A[0][0],10,MPI_DOIBLE,rank+1,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
if(rank==1){
MPI_Recv(&A[0][0],10,MPI_DOIBLE,rank-1,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,*status);
}
```